# Can I typedef a template template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

In C++ library headers, we'll sometimes see the following to improve legibility of the code inside a class:

```
template<typename MyExplicitelyLongTemplateParameter>
class C
{
public:
    typedef MyExplicitelyLongTemplateParameter P;

    // Use "P" and keep your sanity.
};
```

My question is, can one do the same with template template parameter?

```
template<template<typename> typename MyExplicitelyLongTemplateParameter>
class C
{
public:
    typedef /* ??? */ P;

    // Use "P" and keep your sanity.
};
```

Comment: I haven't come across this syntax before. What does it do?

Comment: I think that should be template<template<typename> class MyExplicitelyLongTemplateParameter>

Answer (score 8):

You can't create a typedef, no, but you can shorten the name:

```
template <template <typename> typename MyExplicitlyLongTemplateParameter>
class C
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    struct P 
    {
        typedef MyExplicitlyLongTemplateParameter<T> Type;
    };

    // Use "P<T>::Type" and keep your sanity.
};
```

Comment: +1, but as noted in the comments above, it should really be `<template <typename> class ...>`.

Answer (score 3):

In the current standard, you can't typedef a template. In the new, upcoming standard, you will be able to....

Comment: And how will someone be able to typedef in the new standard?