# GCC error when typedef name coincides with variadic template parameter name

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, compiler-errors, variadic-templates

I stumbled on a strange interaction between `typedef` and variadic template parameters that I'd like to understand. The following code compiles with clang but gives an error with GCC:

```
template<typename T> // no error if this is not a template
struct Traits;

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
template<typename ...args>
void function(args... e) {}

template<typename T>
struct Caller {
    typedef typename Traits<T>::types traits_types; // no error if this is changed to a 'using' directive

    template<typename ...types> // no error if the pack is converted to a single parameter
    static void method(types... e) {
        function<traits_types>(e...);
    }
};
```

## GCC behavior

When I compile (not link) this with GCC, I get an error on line 14:

```
$ g++-9.2.0 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -std=c++11 -c test.cpp
test.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Caller<T>::method(types ...)’:
test.cpp:14:31: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
   14 |         function<traits_types>(e...);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
test.cpp:14:31: note:         ‘types’
$
```

It acts as if GCC first substitutes in the definition of `traits_types`, which would produce

```
template<typename ...types>
static void method(types... e) {
    function<typename Traits<T>::types>(e...);
}
```

and then evaluates template parameter substitution, at which point it sees the last occurrence of the token `types` as an unexpanded parameter pack and produces an error accordingly.

I've tested this with GCC 6.4.0, 7.3.0, 8.2.0, 8.3.0, 9.1.0, and 9.2.0, as well as a couple older versions, and the behavior is consistent among all of them.

## clang behavior

However, when I compile this with clang, it works fine.

```
$ clang++-8 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -std=c++11 -c test.cpp
$
```

This seems as if it first substitutes in for the parameter pack `types` and *then* handles the name `traits_types`.

I see this behavior consistently in clang 6.0.0, 7.0.1, and 8.0.1, and a couple older versions.

## Question

In standard C++11, is GCC correct to give the error that it does, or is the code valid? Or is it undefined/implementation-defined/otherwise unspecified?

I've looked through much of [cppreference.com's content on templates and typedefs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language) without finding anything that clearly addresses this case. I also checked several other questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029722/typedef-and-template-parameter-with-same-name), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099826/typedef-with-template-parameter-in-c), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845950/can-i-typedef-a-template-template-parameter), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558976/variadic-templates-with-template-function-names), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180847/gcc-doesnt-accept-pack-expansion-in-default-template-argument), etc.), all of which seem similar but don't quite apply to this situation, as far as I can tell.

If this is in fact a compiler bug, a link to a relevant issue in the bug tracker confirming that GCC (or clang, if applicable) doesn't handle this correctly would settle the question pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's a bug. What you observed as *"it acts as if GCC first substitutes in the definition of traits_types"*, is followed by a manifestation of [GCC bug 90189](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90189):

> Source:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>     using CommonName = char;
> };
>
> template <typename T, typename... CommonName>
> struct B {
>     using V = typename T::CommonName;
> };
>
> template struct B<A>;
>
>
> Output:
>
> <source>:7:37: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
>     7 |     using V = typename T::CommonName;
>       |                                     ^
> <source>:7:37: note:         'CommonName'
> Compiler returned: 1
> ```
>
> Rejected by all GCC versions. Accepted by clang, msvc.

GCC acts like you wrote `typename Traits<T>::types` directly, and then it gets confused by the dependent name `types` being the same as the name of the template parameter pack. You can get around it by giving the pack a different name, but in standard C++ the dependent name can be the same as the name of the pack. Because one must be qualified, whereas the other is unqualified, there should be no ambiguity.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For my own educational purposes, do you know if there's something particular in the standard I could look at to justify this?

Comment: @DavidZ - https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#variadic-5 seems the most pertinent. It basically says "this is a valid pattern if it's okay to put a regular template parameter there". Well, a regular template parameter doesn't keep its meaning as a template parameter when it's a nested name. So neither should the pack.